# Как настроить Document root для Yii2

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

У меня в корне лежат все файлы из каталога basic, нужно перенаправлять на папку web на index.php, использовал этот скрипт

```
DocumentRoot "var/www/data/www/site.ua/basic/web"

<Directory "var/www/data/www/site.ua/basic/web">
   # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
   RewriteEngine on
   # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
   RewriteRule . index.php

   # ...other settings...
 </Directory>
```

в файле .htaccess

Получаю ошибку Iternal sever 500

Моя корневая директория - `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  - `/var/www/data/www/site.ua`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете все папки, кроме web, поместить в отдельную папку (например в папку framework), из папки web перенести все файлы в корень, и отредактировать index.php

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/framework/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/framework/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/framework/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Я не знаю подводных камней, и все будет в таком варианте работать, но дефолтный шаблон открывается.

Answer (score 1):

Нужен подробный текст ошибки. Попробуйте прописать не в .htaccess, а в конфиги апача настройку виртуального хоста:

```
          <VirtualHost "*:80">
          DocumentRoot "/home/example/web"
          ServerName example.ru
          <Directory "/home/example/web">
              RewriteEngine on
              Options FollowSymLinks Options all AllowOverride All
              allow from all
              Require all granted

              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule . index.php

          </Directory>
          </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: К сожалению не имею доступ к  настройкам хоста, так как арендую у хостера...

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о получаемой ошибке и какой url открываете.